# How to format decimal places which contains different values

Tags: java

```
double d1 = "4.0"
double d2 = "4.2"
double d3 = "4.28"
```

I perform an arithmetic operation and it results in the above values with a maximum scale of 2. For `d1`, I would prefer that the value be formatted to a simple integer (e.g. `4` in this case) and the formatting on the rest of the values `d2, d3` . How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

for example:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.##");
System.out.println(df.format(d1));
System.out.println(df.format(d2));
System.out.println(df.format(d3));
```

read the doc to get the best format pattern for your needs.